# SharePoint list, restrict view of particular item within the list

Tags: list, view, item

I want to create a list to track complaints progress and results but limit who can see what items. In particular I want to hide 1 item from a particular group
but leave it visible for other groups who have access to the list. All these people have permission to change items so any solutions that are related to amending views won't work because they can change the views themselves if they want to.

Answer (score 3):

Use Audience Targeting.

That's the Out of Box feature available to meet your requirement. Create two separate views. In one view you give access to all groups while for other view you edit the page and in Audience targeting for that particular view, you list down the groups name you want to give access to.

Comment: the issue here is the group I want to restrict the item from have permissions to write / change the list so could change their view and access the data, which I don't want them to see

Comment: Then give unique permission to the list or the folder or the item..

Comment: is there a way to do the same thing without using two seperate views or lists. Basically have a single list view and one group only sees some of the items while others can see everything?

Comment: Yes those some of the items needs unique permission. Or if you have some kind of filter/policy for items which should be visible to a set of user, you can write custom scripts on the aspx page.