# One list for all departments (Permissions)

Tags: 2013, list, permissions

I have a main list, which I distribute on different pages.
The idea is that different departments will fill in their tasks and only be able to read/write information associated with their department.

The only solution I have is to control this through views. But I do not know if this is a good solution. It is important that users do not access other departmental tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you strictly want to go with *one* main list, you'd need to handle this with views and preferably using audience targeting. A similar question can be found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183431/sharepoint-list-restrict-view-of-particular-item-within-the-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). However, if you will handle the requirement like this, users still have the same permission to items which wouldn't be shown in the view targeted to them - the items just wouldn't be directly visible, although quite trivially accessible with some understanding of SP.

Another (likely bad) option would be to handle list items each with unique permissions, but this would be a terrible solution from managing point of view.

Generally I'd suggest to handle this requirement by creating several lists. Possible usage of lookup fields and/or content queries for simulating "a main list" could be implemented on top of that.

Comment: The idea was never to use only one list. But it feels very difficult to try to merge multiple lists into "one".  tried to use lookup, but I did not understand how I would get it to retrieve all data.  But do you think that one list is a bad alternative?

Comment: SP lists don't really support the real-world definition of merging, but the content querying option I mention would be available, if you'd e.g. use a same custom content type for your lists which you'd then use as a base for your query ("get all items where *content type* = *your custom content type*"). Lookups would be for sharing content between the lists (e.g. if you'd have to populate a column with options, it would be easier to do it via another list to simplify list management). One list is a bad option if your "other users MUST NOT access other tasks" is a strict requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As @moe said one possible solution is to manually assign permissions to items.

To automate this process via a SharePoint designer workflow:

1. Add groups with department names.
2. Against each item, create a column which stores which department this item is meant for.
3. Then adding a step in workflow to first remove all permissions and then assign permission to the group name stored in the column of the item.

This way you will not have to use views. Whether the user opens "All items" view or opens the list itself, he will be able to see only the items assigned to his department.

Comment: This would have been interesting to test, it seems like a good option!, unfortunately, we are not allowed use Sharepoint designer.